# 3 different subgroup tests. When to use each? are they all equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am having a hard time understanding when to use each different subgroup test and if given at any case, its sufficient to use either to proof that the given subgroup is truly a subgroup.

**One-Step Subgroup Test**
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a nonempty subset of $G$. Then, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$, whenever $a$ and $b$ are in $H$.

**Two-Step Subgroup Test**
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a nonempty subset of $G$. Then, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $ab \in H$ whenever $a,b \in H$ (closed under multiplication), and $a^{-1} \in H$ whenever $a \in H$ (closed under taking inverses).

**Finite Subgroup Test**
Let $H$ be a nonempty finite subset of a group $G$. Then, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $H$ is closed under the operation of $G$.

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Most of the times it is necessary to prove that if $a\in H<G$ then $a^{-1}\in H$, so that the "One-Set Subgroup Test" becomes kind of a "two step" proof. It all depends on the nature of the problem, i.e., on the nature of the groups and subgroups given.

Comment: I also noticed that all the 3 subgroup tests proofs involved using the one-step subgroup test. I guess I will try multiple of problems and try all 3 and hopefully I would see which will fit the nature of the groups and subgroups

Comment: Also, you will see that this is more for understanding the "language" of "subgroup, normal subgroup, quotient group" etc. In real life it will be obvious whether or not a subset is a subgroup most of the time. For example, the set of upper unitriangular matrices in the group $GL_n(K)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all equivalent. They are really just restatements of the the definition of a subgroup. The definition says that the subset must form a group on its own. That means the subset $H\subseteq G$ contains the identity, the inverses and is closed.

All these properties can be encompassed with each of the three tests, the "trickiest" being the finite case as it is not as evidently true but it can be shown. But in all cases they are equivalent and which you use is up to you and is usually determined by which is easiest to see and prove.

Though in most cases it obvious if it is a subgroup or not.

Comment: They are not always all equivalent. As the name suggests, the last one is true only for finite subgroups (or rather subsets).

Comment: Yes but i assumed that was given by the name

Comment: Hey guys, a quick question. I am trying to figure out why do we even need these subgroup tests. We can prove a subgroup is a subgroup by using the definition of a group and subgroup. Then other than the process of using such subgroup being easier, is their any other reason why we even need these subgroup tests?

Comment: Thank you for your response guys, its really helping me

Comment: It has to do with convinience of options. In some situation one method is best, in other situations other works better. I also remember a fourth method, image of a homomorphism.